# Invert 20X20 matrix with math.net numerics

Tags: matrix, matrix-inverse, mathnet-numerics

I need to invert a 20X20 matrix, but I am getting incorrect results.

I have created a test program using some values from my application:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

namespace MathNetTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Matrix<double> A = new DenseMatrix(20,20) ;

      A[0,0] = 3.3556377856E-06 ;
      A[0,1] = 7.8402752E-05 ;
      A[0,2] = 0.00183184 ;
      A[0,3] = 0.0428 ;
      A[0,4] = 1 ;
      A[0,5] = 0 ;
      A[0,6] = 0 ;
      A[0,7] = 0 ;
      A[0,8] = 0 ;
      A[0,9] = 0 ;
      A[0,10] = 0 ;
      A[0,11] = 0 ;
      A[0,12] = 0 ;
      A[0,13] = 0 ;
      A[0,14] = 0 ;
      A[0,15] = 0 ;
      A[0,16] = 0 ;
      A[0,17] = 0 ;
      A[0,18] = 0 ;
      A[0,19] = 0 ;
      A[1,0] = 0.000313611008 ;
      A[1,1] = 0.00549552 ;
      A[1,2] = 0.0856 ;
      A[1,3] = 1 ;
      A[1,4] = 0 ;
      A[1,5] = 0 ;
      A[1,6] = 0 ;
      A[1,7] = 0 ;
      A[1,8] = 0 ;
      A[1,9] = 0 ;
      A[1,10] = 0 ;
      A[1,11] = 0 ;
      A[1,12] = 0 ;
      A[1,13] = 0 ;
      A[1,14] = 0 ;
      A[1,15] = 0 ;
      A[1,16] = 0 ;
      A[1,17] = 0 ;
      A[1,18] = 0 ;
      A[1,19] = 0 ;
      A[2,0] = 0.02198208 ;
      A[2,1] = 0.2568 ;
      A[2,2] = 2 ;
      A[2,3] = 0 ;
      A[2,4] = 0 ;
      A[2,5] = 0 ;
      A[2,6] = 0 ;
      A[2,7] = 0 ;
      A[2,8] = 0 ;
      A[2,9] = 0 ;
      A[2,10] = 0 ;
      A[2,11] = 0 ;
      A[2,12] = 0 ;
      A[2,13] = 0 ;
      A[2,14] = 0 ;
      A[2,15] = 0 ;
      A[2,16] = 0 ;
      A[2,17] = 0 ;
      A[2,18] = 0 ;
      A[2,19] = 0 ;
      A[3,0] = 1.0272 ;
      A[3,1] = 6 ;
      A[3,2] = 0 ;
      A[3,3] = 0 ;
      A[3,4] = 0 ;
      A[3,5] = 0 ;
      A[3,6] = 0 ;
      A[3,7] = 0 ;
      A[3,8] = 0 ;
      A[3,9] = 0 ;
      A[3,10] = 0 ;
      A[3,11] = 0 ;
      A[3,12] = 0 ;
      A[3,13] = 0 ;
      A[3,14] = 0 ;
      A[3,15] = 0 ;
      A[3,16] = 0 ;
      A[3,17] = 0 ;
      A[3,18] = 0 ;
      A[3,19] = 0 ;
      A[4,0] = -4.5954068161E-06 ;
      A[4,1] = -9.9252847E-05 ;
      A[4,2] = -0.00214369 ;
      A[4,3] = -0.0463 ;
      A[4,4] = -1 ;
      A[4,5] = 4.5954068161E-06 ;
      A[4,6] = 9.9252847E-05 ;
      A[4,7] = 0.00214369 ;
      A[4,8] = 0.0463 ;
      A[4,9] = 1 ;
      A[4,10] = 0 ;
      A[4,11] = 0 ;
      A[4,12] = 0 ;
      A[4,13] = 0 ;
      A[4,14] = 0 ;
      A[4,15] = 0 ;
      A[4,16] = 0 ;
      A[4,17] = 0 ;
      A[4,18] = 0 ;
      A[4,19] = 0 ;
      A[5,0] = -0.000397011388 ;
      A[5,1] = -0.00643107 ;
      A[5,2] = -0.0926 ;
      A[5,3] = -1 ;
      A[5,4] = 0 ;
      A[5,5] = 0.000397011388 ;
      A[5,6] = 0.00643107 ;
      A[5,7] = 0.0926 ;
      A[5,8] = 1 ;
      A[5,9] = 0 ;
      A[5,10] = 0 ;
      A[5,11] = 0 ;
      A[5,12] = 0 ;
      A[5,13] = 0 ;
      A[5,14] = 0 ;
      A[5,15] = 0 ;
      A[5,16] = 0 ;
      A[5,17] = 0 ;
      A[5,18] = 0 ;
      A[5,19] = 0 ;
      A[6,0] = -0.02572428 ;
      A[6,1] = -0.2778 ;
      A[6,2] = -2 ;
      A[6,3] = 0 ;
      A[6,4] = 0 ;
      A[6,5] = 0.02572428 ;
      A[6,6] = 0.2778 ;
      A[6,7] = 2 ;
      A[6,8] = 0 ;
      A[6,9] = 0 ;
      A[6,10] = 0 ;
      A[6,11] = 0 ;
      A[6,12] = 0 ;
      A[6,13] = 0 ;
      A[6,14] = 0 ;
      A[6,15] = 0 ;
      A[6,16] = 0 ;
      A[6,17] = 0 ;
      A[6,18] = 0 ;
      A[6,19] = 0 ;
      A[7,0] = -1.1112 ;
      A[7,1] = -6 ;
      A[7,2] = 0 ;
      A[7,3] = 0 ;
      A[7,4] = 0 ;
      A[7,5] = 1.1112 ;
      A[7,6] = 6 ;
      A[7,7] = 0 ;
      A[7,8] = 0 ;
      A[7,9] = 0 ;
      A[7,10] = 0 ;
      A[7,11] = 0 ;
      A[7,12] = 0 ;
      A[7,13] = 0 ;
      A[7,14] = 0 ;
      A[7,15] = 0 ;
      A[7,16] = 0 ;
      A[7,17] = 0 ;
      A[7,18] = 0 ;
      A[7,19] = 0 ;
      A[8,0] = 0 ;
      A[8,1] = 0 ;
      A[8,2] = 0 ;
      A[8,3] = 0 ;
      A[8,4] = 0 ;
      A[8,5] = -6.1505984016E-06 ;
      A[8,6] = -0.000123505992 ;
      A[8,7] = -0.00248004 ;
      A[8,8] = -0.0498 ;
      A[8,9] = -1 ;
      A[8,10] = 6.1505984016E-06 ;
      A[8,11] = 0.000123505992 ;
      A[8,12] = 0.00248004 ;
      A[8,13] = 0.0498 ;
      A[8,14] = 1 ;
      A[8,15] = 0 ;
      A[8,16] = 0 ;
      A[8,17] = 0 ;
      A[8,18] = 0 ;
      A[8,19] = 0 ;
      A[9,0] = 0 ;
      A[9,1] = 0 ;
      A[9,2] = 0 ;
      A[9,3] = 0 ;
      A[9,4] = 0 ;
      A[9,5] = -0.000494023968 ;
      A[9,6] = -0.00744012 ;
      A[9,7] = -0.0996 ;
      A[9,8] = -1 ;
      A[9,9] = 0 ;
      A[9,10] = 0.000494023968 ;
      A[9,11] = 0.00744012 ;
      A[9,12] = 0.0996 ;
      A[9,13] = 1 ;
      A[9,14] = 0 ;
      A[9,15] = 0 ;
      A[9,16] = 0 ;
      A[9,17] = 0 ;
      A[9,18] = 0 ;
      A[9,19] = 0 ;
      A[10,0] = 0 ;
      A[10,1] = 0 ;
      A[10,2] = 0 ;
      A[10,3] = 0 ;
      A[10,4] = 0 ;
      A[10,5] = -0.02976048 ;
      A[10,6] = -0.2988 ;
      A[10,7] = -2 ;
      A[10,8] = 0 ;
      A[10,9] = 0 ;
      A[10,10] = 0.02976048 ;
      A[10,11] = 0.2988 ;
      A[10,12] = 2 ;
      A[10,13] = 0 ;
      A[10,14] = 0 ;
      A[10,15] = 0 ;
      A[10,16] = 0 ;
      A[10,17] = 0 ;
      A[10,18] = 0 ;
      A[10,19] = 0 ;
      A[11,0] = 0 ;
      A[11,1] = 0 ;
      A[11,2] = 0 ;
      A[11,3] = 0 ;
      A[11,4] = 0 ;
      A[11,5] = -1.1952 ;
      A[11,6] = -6 ;
      A[11,7] = 0 ;
      A[11,8] = 0 ;
      A[11,9] = 0 ;
      A[11,10] = 1.1952 ;
      A[11,11] = 6 ;
      A[11,12] = 0 ;
      A[11,13] = 0 ;
      A[11,14] = 0 ;
      A[11,15] = 0 ;
      A[11,16] = 0 ;
      A[11,17] = 0 ;
      A[11,18] = 0 ;
      A[11,19] = 0 ;
      A[12,0] = 0 ;
      A[12,1] = 0 ;
      A[12,2] = 0 ;
      A[12,3] = 0 ;
      A[12,4] = 0 ;
      A[12,5] = 0 ;
      A[12,6] = 0 ;
      A[12,7] = 0 ;
      A[12,8] = 0 ;
      A[12,9] = 0 ;
      A[12,10] = -8.0706559921E-06 ;
      A[12,11] = -0.000151419437 ;
      A[12,12] = -0.00284089 ;
      A[12,13] = -0.0533 ;
      A[12,14] = -1 ;
      A[12,15] = 8.0706559921E-06 ;
      A[12,16] = 0.000151419437 ;
      A[12,17] = 0.00284089 ;
      A[12,18] = 0.0533 ;
      A[12,19] = 1 ;
      A[13,0] = 0 ;
      A[13,1] = 0 ;
      A[13,2] = 0 ;
      A[13,3] = 0 ;
      A[13,4] = 0 ;
      A[13,5] = 0 ;
      A[13,6] = 0 ;
      A[13,7] = 0 ;
      A[13,8] = 0 ;
      A[13,9] = 0 ;
      A[13,10] = -0.000605677748 ;
      A[13,11] = -0.00852267 ;
      A[13,12] = -0.1066 ;
      A[13,13] = -1 ;
      A[13,14] = 0 ;
      A[13,15] = 0.000605677748 ;
      A[13,16] = 0.00852267 ;
      A[13,17] = 0.1066 ;
      A[13,18] = 1 ;
      A[13,19] = 0 ;
      A[14,0] = 0 ;
      A[14,1] = 0 ;
      A[14,2] = 0 ;
      A[14,3] = 0 ;
      A[14,4] = 0 ;
      A[14,5] = 0 ;
      A[14,6] = 0 ;
      A[14,7] = 0 ;
      A[14,8] = 0 ;
      A[14,9] = 0 ;
      A[14,10] = -0.03409068 ;
      A[14,11] = -0.3198 ;
      A[14,12] = -2 ;
      A[14,13] = 0 ;
      A[14,14] = 0 ;
      A[14,15] = 0.03409068 ;
      A[14,16] = 0.3198 ;
      A[14,17] = 2 ;
      A[14,18] = 0 ;
      A[14,19] = 0 ;
      A[15,0] = 0 ;
      A[15,1] = 0 ;
      A[15,2] = 0 ;
      A[15,3] = 0 ;
      A[15,4] = 0 ;
      A[15,5] = 0 ;
      A[15,6] = 0 ;
      A[15,7] = 0 ;
      A[15,8] = 0 ;
      A[15,9] = 0 ;
      A[15,10] = -1.2792 ;
      A[15,11] = -6 ;
      A[15,12] = 0 ;
      A[15,13] = 0 ;
      A[15,14] = 0 ;
      A[15,15] = 1.2792 ;
      A[15,16] = 6 ;
      A[15,17] = 0 ;
      A[15,18] = 0 ;
      A[15,19] = 0 ;
      A[16,0] = 0 ;
      A[16,1] = 0 ;
      A[16,2] = 0 ;
      A[16,3] = 0 ;
      A[16,4] = 0 ;
      A[16,5] = 0 ;
      A[16,6] = 0 ;
      A[16,7] = 0 ;
      A[16,8] = 0 ;
      A[16,9] = 0 ;
      A[16,10] = 0 ;
      A[16,11] = 0 ;
      A[16,12] = 0 ;
      A[16,13] = 0 ;
      A[16,14] = 0 ;
      A[16,15] = 3.3556377856E-06 ;
      A[16,16] = 7.8402752E-05 ;
      A[16,17] = 0.00183184 ;
      A[16,18] = 0.0428 ;
      A[16,19] = 1 ;
      A[17,0] = 0 ;
      A[17,1] = 0 ;
      A[17,2] = 0 ;
      A[17,3] = 0 ;
      A[17,4] = 0 ;
      A[17,5] = 0 ;
      A[17,6] = 0 ;
      A[17,7] = 0 ;
      A[17,8] = 0 ;
      A[17,9] = 0 ;
      A[17,10] = 0 ;
      A[17,11] = 0 ;
      A[17,12] = 0 ;
      A[17,13] = 0 ;
      A[17,14] = 0 ;
      A[17,15] = 0.000313611008 ;
      A[17,16] = 0.00549552 ;
      A[17,17] = 0.0856 ;
      A[17,18] = 1 ;
      A[17,19] = 0 ;
      A[18,0] = 0 ;
      A[18,1] = 0 ;
      A[18,2] = 0 ;
      A[18,3] = 0 ;
      A[18,4] = 0 ;
      A[18,5] = 0 ;
      A[18,6] = 0 ;
      A[18,7] = 0 ;
      A[18,8] = 0 ;
      A[18,9] = 0 ;
      A[18,10] = 0 ;
      A[18,11] = 0 ;
      A[18,12] = 0 ;
      A[18,13] = 0 ;
      A[18,14] = 0 ;
      A[18,15] = 0.02198208 ;
      A[18,16] = 0.2568 ;
      A[18,17] = 2 ;
      A[18,18] = 0 ;
      A[18,19] = 0 ;
      A[19,0] = 0 ;
      A[19,1] = 0 ;
      A[19,2] = 0 ;
      A[19,3] = 0 ;
      A[19,4] = 0 ;
      A[19,5] = 0 ;
      A[19,6] = 0 ;
      A[19,7] = 0 ;
      A[19,8] = 0 ;
      A[19,9] = 0 ;
      A[19,10] = 0 ;
      A[19,11] = 0 ;
      A[19,12] = 0 ;
      A[19,13] = 0 ;
      A[19,14] = 0 ;
      A[19,15] = 1.0272 ;
      A[19,16] = 6 ;
      A[19,17] = 0 ;
      A[19,18] = 0 ;
      A[19,19] = 0 ;

      double  det = A.Determinant() ;
      Matrix<double> B = A.Inverse() ;

      Matrix<double> I1 = B.Multiply(A) ;

      for ( int i1 = 0 ; i1 < 20 ; i1++ )
      {
        for ( int i2 = 0 ; i2 < 20 ; i2++ )
        {
          Debug.Write ( String.Format("{0:f20} ", I1[i1,i2]) ) ;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("") ;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The determinant of the matrix is not zero.

When I multiply the matrix with its supposed inverse, the result should of course be an identity matrix, but it is not.

Am I doing something wrong?

This is the result of multiplying A*B, dumped with format {0:f4}

```
3.0516 29.8308 403.7012 4502.0000 0.0000 0.3089 11.5556 237.5566 2906.0000 0.0000 1.5993 13.8137 -143.7188 -6196.0000 -185344.0000 -4.0366 -58.6136 -757.0625 -7344.0000 0.0000
-0.3510 -4.0969 -69.5088 -768.2500 0.0000 -0.0526 -1.9899 -40.7600 -502.5000 0.0000 -0.2736 -2.3473 23.8477 1050.0000 31616.0000 0.6906 10.0144 130.0352 1267.0000 0.0000
0.0228 0.3309 5.5107 50.7500 0.0000 0.0032 0.1254 2.5747 31.2500 0.0000 0.0175 0.1500 -1.5508 -68.0000 -2048.0000 -0.0442 -0.6423 -8.3008 -81.0000 0.0000
-0.0006 -0.0094 -0.1284 -0.4375 0.0000 -0.0001 -0.0037 -0.0748 -0.9063 0.0000 -0.0005 -0.0040 0.0499 2.0313 60.0000 0.0012 0.0182 0.2345 2.2813 0.0000
0.0000 0.0001 0.0011 0.0118 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0006 0.0082 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0009 -0.0286 -0.7500 0.0000 -0.0002 -0.0020 -0.0192 0.0000
-2.6921 -51.6272 -833.1016 -9718.0000 0.0000 -3.0679 -54.7289 -654.8184 -6060.0000 0.0000 -2.0779 -18.6694 -73.3594 7480.0000 300032.0000 9.4324 138.8463 1813.2656 17688.0000 0.0000
0.5280 9.9864 160.6318 1869.0000 0.0000 0.7568 11.2792 124.2202 1164.2500 0.0000 0.4065 3.6434 11.8789 -1495.0000 -58240.0000 -1.8032 -26.5348 -346.0117 -3378.0000 0.0000
-0.0386 -0.7200 -11.5379 -133.6250 0.0000 -0.0529 -0.7244 -7.8596 -84.0938 0.0000 -0.0297 -0.2653 -0.6511 108.6875 4208.0000 0.1288 1.8943 24.7454 241.4375 0.0000
0.0012 0.0230 0.3657 4.2476 0.0000 0.0016 0.0227 0.2800 3.6421 0.0000 0.0010 0.0086 0.0187 -3.4785 -134.2500 -0.0041 -0.0600 -0.7838 -7.6426 0.0000
0.0000 -0.0003 -0.0046 -0.0540 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0003 -0.0035 -0.0333 1.0000 0.0000 -0.0001 -0.0006 0.0354 1.5000 0.0001 0.0007 0.0098 0.0963 0.0000
2.2159 32.5541 447.8652 4992.0000 0.0000 0.4233 13.3315 260.0723 3196.0000 0.0000 3.6278 30.1333 123.3438 -2092.0000 -123904.0000 -5.2220 -76.3832 -1004.1719 -9940.0000 0.0000
-0.4501 -6.7982 -95.6135 -1070.5000 0.0000 -0.1371 -3.2576 -57.6484 -670.7500 0.0000 -0.5277 -5.0465 -26.8984 438.0000 26368.0000 1.1128 16.3116 213.9023 2119.0000 0.0000
0.0345 0.5310 7.6026 85.4688 0.0000 0.0140 0.2881 4.7319 53.7969 0.0000 0.0401 0.4588 3.1641 -35.5625 -2112.0000 -0.0889 -1.3052 -17.1086 -169.0000 0.0000
-0.0012 -0.0186 -0.2685 -3.0322 0.0000 -0.0006 -0.0110 -0.1729 -1.9248 0.0000 -0.0014 -0.0156 -0.0786 2.2617 75.0000 0.0032 0.0464 0.6079 5.9980 0.0000
0.0000 0.0002 0.0036 0.0406 0.0000 0.0000 0.0002 0.0023 0.0255 0.0000 0.0000 0.0002 0.0011 -0.0169 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0006 -0.0081 -0.0800 0.0000
0.5480 3.9908 14.1191 -4.0000 0.0000 -1.1027 -9.8011 -53.9141 -24.0000 0.0000 0.7832 9.6061 -12.8750 24.0000 0.0000 0.9848 0.0848 1.1563 -8.0000 0.0000
-0.0930 -0.6594 -2.1245 9.7500 0.0000 0.1894 1.6800 8.6348 -0.5000 0.0000 -0.1339 -1.6457 2.9570 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0029 0.9727 -0.6367 -2.0000 0.0000
0.0060 0.0438 0.1286 -0.2344 0.0000 -0.0122 -0.1075 -0.5685 -0.2500 0.0000 0.0087 0.1047 -0.1809 0.6250 0.0000 -0.0002 0.0011 1.0481 -0.3750 0.0000
-0.0002 -0.0012 -0.0043 -0.0103 0.0000 0.0003 0.0031 0.0167 0.0059 0.0000 -0.0002 -0.0030 0.0046 0.0117 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0001 -0.0014 1.0078 0.0000
0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0002 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0001 1.0000
```

Comment: How big are the errors? Could it be due to rounding?

Comment: @AxelKemper I have added the results A*B to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your numbers with [this C# Matrix Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19032/C-Matrix-Library). The determinant routine threw an exception and complained about your matrix to be close to singular.

To check the matrix inversion capability, you could square your matrix and calculate the inverse of the result.

Comment: @AlexKemper Thanks Alex. You are almost certainly right. I have found an error in my code setting up the matrix. Having fixed that, the matrix inversion works perfectly. In addition, I have switched to using the Solve method, since I only needed to invert the matrix to solve a set of linear equations.